# VNC - full screen (Laptop viewer)

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I have a winXP laptop with vnc viewer installed.
I am connecting from the laptop to my other fedora machine.
In the viewer when I set to full screen it is not streched, meaning i need to scroll up and down to see the desktop boundries.
Changing the server resolution did not help, how can i make the viewer to be streched all over the lap top screen?

Thanks

Comment: Your question does not include enough specific details to give you very a very precise answer. Please include information such as what software you are using for the vnc viewer and server compnents. There are lots of different programs and they all have settings in different places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some VNC servers and viewers have a "scale" function that can change the output size. I know UltraVNC supports this for example. Also the Xvnc compnent you are probably using to export your fedora box supports scaling, but it is more difficult to setup on that end.